# helm install ingress does not set up

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

So i have set up an AWS EKS cluster (using fargate), and intend to use it for gitlab CI/CD integration

Then tried to set up the base domain based on [this doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/quick_start_guide.html#install-ingress)

```
helm repo add nginx-stable https://helm.nginx.com/stable
helm repo update
helm install nginx-ingress nginx-stable/nginx-ingress
```

`kubectl get service nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress -ojson | jq -r '.status.loadBalancer.ingress[].ip'` always returns `null` even after waiting for long

Basically I need a loadBalancer IP for setting up base domain in gitlab.

Read that i need to set service type to loadBalancer, so retried with
 `helm install nginx-ingress nginx-stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.service.type=LoadBalancer`

Same result

result of `kubectl get service nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress -ojson` includes

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Service",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "meta.helm.sh/release-name": "nginx-ingress",
            "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": "default"
        },
        "creationTimestamp": "2021-03-26T19:49:02Z",
        "finalizers": [
            "service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup"
        ],
        "labels": {
            "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "nginx-ingress",
            "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": "Helm",
            "app.kubernetes.io/name": "nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress",
            "helm.sh/chart": "nginx-ingress-0.8.1"
        },
   .
   .
   .
   .
    "status": {
        "loadBalancer": {
            "ingress": [
                {
                    "hostname": "<xyz-key>.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on **how to obtain a load balancer IP address** would be appreciated

Comment: The hostname which you see is the DNS name of the Load Balancer created. That's the format AWS used for Load Balancer's. You don't need IP in this case.

Comment: Running the command `kubectl get service nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress -ojson | jq -r '.status.loadBalancer.ingress[]'` would return the same hostname.

Answer (score 1):

As @rockn-rolla mentioned in the comments, an Elastic Load Balancer provisioned through nginx-ingress on EKS returns is exposed by a hostname. The Load Balancer does have IP addresses tied to the subnets that it's deployed into (Elastic Network Interfaces), but its possible that they change. If you have a domain name, you can point a custom subdomain to the load balancer and provide that to GitLab. This GitLab blog has additional details: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/05/05/deploying-application-eks/